# Access the files from Onedrive and load in to sql server table using SSIS package 2015

Tags: sql-server, ssis, onedrive

I have files in Onedrive folder and wanted to load in to sql server table using SSIS.

How to load the files from onedrive to sql server table?

Comment: I do not think `data-warehouse` tag here is relevant, this question needs `onedrive` `SSIS` `sql-server` tags

Comment: Any help is really appreciated. Can any one suggest how we can load file from Microsoft Onedrive to sql server table.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, i m new to this stackoverflow. Any idea to achieve this load?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not my area, I was only commenting about tags. If you have more relevant tags for your question people who are following those tags can see your question and you might get your answer quicker.

Answer (score 0):

You can designate your local file path in your SSIS as source for data flow.  This works even if your local path is syncing with OneDrive.

However, it seems like you would like to set up a SSIS package that can access the online instance of the file on OneDrive.

I think for that, you can use 3rd party extension such as [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KingswaySoft.SSISIntegrationToolkitforMicrosoftOneDrive) from KingswaySoft: